# Adding order by in PHP query

Tags: php, sql

I have tried to add `DESC` and `ASC` to this but I still can't get it to order properly. Just want to make sure I am trying in the correct spot.

```
$query = $db->query("
        SELECT n.*, COUNT(c.id) as replies, u.username, u.displaygroup, u.usergroup, u.avatar
        FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "news n
        LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PREFIX . "newscomments c ON (c.nid = n.id)
        LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PREFIX . "users u ON (u.uid = n.uid)
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET($cid, n.cid)
        GROUP BY n.id
        ORDER BY n.date_posted
        LIMIT $start, $perpage
    ");
```

I have tried

```
ORDER BY n.date_posted DESC
```

and

```
ORDER BY n.date_posted ASC
```

Is that the correct place to put this? I want the latest news to be on top.

Comment: Yes. If you need it more granular: `n.date_posted DESC, n.id DESC`

Comment: I tried it as I want to order by the date. Want the most recent posts to be on top. Changed nothing for me.

Comment: Are you trying to get the most recent News on top or most recent Comment(s) on top? Because the line `WHERE FIND_IN_SET($cid, n.cid)` seems to be the limiting factor.

Comment: I want the latest news on top. So based on date_posted todays post should be on top.

Answer (score 0):

Try restructuring your replies as a subquery:

```
$query = $db->query("                                                          
    SELECT 
      n.*,                                                                
      (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "newscomments c WHERE c.id = n.id) as replies,
       u.username, u.displaygroup, u.usergroup, u.avatar                       
    FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "news n                                            
    LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PREFIX . "users u ON (u.uid = n.uid)                   
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET($cid, n.cid)                                             
    ORDER BY n.date_posted                                                     
    LIMIT $start, $perpage                                                     
");
```

Comment: Did not work. I have never seen a query like this as I am new to PHP. It is ordering the posts by date with oldest on top. But I am not sure what needs changed.

Comment: use ORDER BY n.date_posted DESC